# Can't find my package path in file explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, filepath

My project package doesn't show in DDMS > File Explorer (I had selected my phone in window devices). I found that an error is shown in logcat, which says can't open file for reading.

Is it possible that I didn't install Eclipse properly? Before that, my project ran well and I could see the project path in the file explorer (under data>data>). After I had make few changes (I don't recall what changes I had made, too many), when doing another project, I uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse, then this error appeared.  I can't find ALL my project package in file explorer.

May I know what is the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the permissions, DDMS will only show the files and folders he has enough access to reach.

You can change these permissions using the tool Android Debug Bridge (ADB).

ADB is located in the folder `platform-tools` in your SDK directory.
On Windows you can access shell by opening a command prompt, go to the SDB path and use the following command:

```
cd (...)\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb shell
```

Once the command shell is opened, you can enter the command `su - root` to get root access.

To change permissions on files and folders, you just need to use the command `chmod`.

**EDIT**: here is an example showing gow to change the right on a specific folder, and all its contents:

```
chmod -R [permissions] [dirname]
```

`R` means recursive, if you remove it, it will only change the permissions of the folder, not its contents. 
In `[permissions]`, put the permissions desired, a full access is for example `777`.
In `[dirname]`, just replace with your folder name.

Example:

```
chmod -R 777 new_folder
```

This command gives full access to the folder "new_folder" and its sub-folders.

Comment: After i enter the command su - root, it show "shell@android:/#"
show what should I type?

Comment: You can navigate to your application folder and change the permissions you need. Be careful to change only the permissions on the files you only need to access. Here is a good link explaining how to use the command `chmod`: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: sorry, but what mean by "your application folder"? cause I can't find where is my project so what folder path should i put? sorry, i'm very new in eclipse and android.

Comment: Your application folder should be in /data/data/your.package.name

Comment: when i type chmod - R 777 /data/data/com.example.abc(my package name), it show "bad mode"
and need me to key in "shell@android:/#" once again..
any idea..T^T

Comment: cause I can't find my package name under data/data folder in file explorer.
Under file explorer just have a empty data folder, nothing inside.

Comment: There is no space between the R and the "-", sorry my mistake. I corrected above.

Comment: is ok. i type chmod -R 777/data/data/com.example.abc
it show:
usage: chmod [OPTION] <MODE> <FILE>
-R, --recursive. change file and directories recursive
-- help display this help and exist

and need me key in  "shell@android:/#" once again..><

Comment: Be careful when you input the command, there is a space after 777, please read the details on how to use it.

Comment: hi, i forget to put a space..
i type chmod -R 777 /data/data/com.example.abc then it show  "shell@android:/#".. mean i already change the permissions?

Comment: i still can't see my package in file explorer.
the data folder still empty..@@

Comment: Yes it worked, you might have also to modify the permissions of the second folder `data` in order to see anything.

Comment: when i type chmod -R 777 /data/data, it show: unable to chmod /data/datacom.android.settings/a/file99: No such file or directory,
then I go file explorer to create a new data folder under data folder. it shown me: mkdir failed for /data/data, File exists.

What should I do?

Comment: thx.. after I re run my project.. i can see my package folder..
Thanks you soooo muchhhhhh.. u save my life^^

Comment: Happy to know I saved a life today :-)