# How to get DB file in android using debugging mode?

Tags: android, database, get

I make an application which cannot run in emulator. So I use android debugging mode or live running. It is running well on my device. and in that application, I create a database for user login. I want to see the data on my database. I mean I want get the database file, and access using a tools like sqlite manager to see the inside. the question is, how to get the database file?

Generally, if I using emulator, it places in data/data/com.package/databases/namedatabase(.db or without it).But when I connect my device in pc and running it, actually there are 3 directories, data, mnt, and system. When I was try to check the subdirectories of data, it is none. There is not any directory in it. so I can't get the database file.

I use eclipse.

Comment: I explained in details how to do in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620330/cant-find-my-package-path-in-file-explorer/16620384#16620384

Comment: This link shows how to view in SQL, something about DDMS:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333412/how-to-view-sql-database-in-eclipse-debug-mode-for-android

Comment: @YoannHercouet ah, finally I get it.thanks so much .. TT

Comment: @YoannHercouet excuse me, i am sorry. I don't know how to upvote, tell me more and I'll do.
Beside that. using chmod -R 777 dir, is it need root access? I already updated my phone into new one and until right now, there are a few of way to get the root access. do you know a way to get the databases on my project without root access? or only this way I could get the databases? thanks for replying and helping me. :)

Comment: Actually you cannot upvote here, but on the answer I give in my link above. About your question, yes you need to root your phone in order to be able to execute this command. You will need to search how to do it for your phone model, you should find a tutorial explaining how to do it on Google I think.