# Cannot Open/view sqlite database file in Eclipse with external Virtual Device Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, virtual-machine

i want to export my sqlite database android,
 so in Eclipse i open **File Explorer**, and go to  **/data/data/[my package]/databases/mydb.sqlite**, and then click **pull a file from the device** button.
it's ok if i use Eclipse Virtual Device Manager, but when i run my android application in External virtual Device Manager i can't get my sqlite database in File Explorer, when i expand **data** folder, it's not response, so i can't go to mydb.sqlite file.
i used Oracle VM Virtual Box to run my android application.

thank's in advance..

Comment: You need to change the permissions on the DB file and directory to be able to see it. You can have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620330/cant-find-my-package-path-in-file-explorer/16620384#16620384

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Thank's Yoann Hercouet!!, now i can view my databases folder

Answer (score 0):

Downlaod **SQLite Database Browser** for view your Database..